# Fragments, ActionBar and Back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

How do I solve the following problem

```
1) FragmentActivity load with ActionBar and a homescreen fragment
2) When user selects "Item1" from ActionBar another Fragment is displayed.
3) User then presses back button to return to the homescreen Fragment
```

Problem:

The homescreen fragment is displayed but the ActionBar still points to "Item1".

What should I do to get ActionBar pointing back to homescreen after back button is pressed ?

Thanks

Comment: call another Fragment's  setHasOptionsMenu(false) method

Comment: could you please put up a screen shot so that it will be easy to  understand.

Comment: well actionbar is being setup within the activity rather than the fragment itself. Pressing back button loads the previous fragment but leaves the actionbar as is.

Comment: Could you please add code that shows what you do to set the menu items - within your Activity and within your Fragments. Ands - as @rickky has pointed out - a screenshot of what is correct and what you actually see would help.

Answer (score 1):

Manage your action bar in your home screen fragment rather than the activity.  After you press back from Item1, somewhere in the lifecycle of the home screen fragment prior to the fragment being active, re-initialize your action bar.